# I'm using react-router-dom and facing this problem . How can I get rid of this?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've installed react-router-dom in node_modules folder and whenever I import react-router-dom it's showing this error

> ./src/index.js Module not found: You attempted to import
>   ../node_modules/rect-router-dom which falls outside of the project
>   src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

How can I  get rid of it?

The code inside the index.js file is the following

```
import React from 'react'; 
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; 
import './index.css'; 
import App from './App'; 
import About from './pages/About' 
import Contact from './pages/Contact' 
import { Route, Link, BrowseRouter as Router } from 'rect-router-dom'; 
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker'; 

const myrouter = ( <Router> </Router> ) 
ReactDOM.render(myrouter, document.getElementById('root')); 
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: Can you show us the import statements?

Comment: your error seems to mention `rect-router-dom` and not `react-router-dom`. Please show your code, you would normally import it as a package (so just `from 'react-router-dom'` and not `from '../node_modules/react-router-dom'`

Comment: Here is the full code in index.js file
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import About from './pages/About'
import Contact from './pages/Contact'
import { Route, Link, BrowseRouter as Router } from 'rect-router-dom';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
const myrouter = (
    <Router>
   
 </Router>
)
ReactDOM.render(myrouter, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();

Comment: yes, as Icepickle pointed in your question, there's the typo in your code too, you import 'rect-router-dom' , should be 'react-router-dom'.

Comment: @MohammedAliFarman Please [edit] your question, and do not just put your code inside the comments, comments are second class citizens and maybe deleted at any point in time

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper way to import it

```
import { Route, Link, BrowseRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Comment: Could you please mark this respose as correct than and that we can close this question?